# StartActivityForResult is not working with Kotlin extension functions?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin-android-extensions, startactivityforresult

This is the extension function which i had created for starting activities for obtaining result, however the activity is getting started, but I'm not getting a call on `onActivityResult`

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Activity.launchActivity(
requestCode: Int = -1,
noinline init: Intent.() -> Unit = {}
) {
val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
intent.init()
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}
```

onActivityResult callback

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Timber.d("onActivityResult".plus(OrderProductFragment::class.java.simpleName))
```

Calling the extension inside a `Fragment`

```
(context as Activity).launchActivity<CartActivity> (1234) {
                putParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.cart_items_key), cartItems)
            }
```

Comment: show your `onActivityResult()` here. So, we can see.

Comment: How do you use your extension function?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I tried with -1,1 and some other combinations, it's not triggering.

Comment: Okay. Debug please.

Comment: I would suggest this change if it makes any difference : `this.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` *(We start activity using extended context, check if it helps)*

Comment: show the code where you are coming back to this fragment or activity ?

Comment: check https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/05/launching-activities-using-kotlin-dsl/

Comment: @JeelVankhede Updated the question, I'd also tried like what you said(adding this) no help

Comment: If you call `startActivityForResult` based on **acitivity context** from Fragment, callback would be received on Activity not on Fragment itself.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it helps or not

Comment: Better is to make another extension for `Fragment` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this  `setResult()` when navigate back to `fragment` or `activity` where you are coming from
ie

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
```

this will invoke the `onActivityResult()` in your `activity` or `fragment` class

**Example**

```
                    val intent = intent
                    intent.putExtra("key", "put values if you want")
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
                    finish()
```